# Resize image and create thumbnail

Tags: php, image, upload, resize

So i have a upload script, that upload a image to a folder, and save the path of the image on the db. I need help resizing the image to 800x600 and create a thumb for it. And a question, do i need to save the thumb path in db?

I want to upload the resized image (800x600), i dont want to save on the server the original (without resize)

Here is what i got:

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_POST['enviar']))
{ //START IF

$nomesitio = $_POST['nome'];
$horario = $_POST['horario'];
$contato = $_POST['contato'];
$morada = $_POST['morada'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$freguesias = $_POST['freguesias'];
$arqName = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
$arqType = $_FILES['arquivo']['type'];
$arqSize = $_FILES['arquivo']['size'];
$arqTemp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
$arqError = $_FILES['arquivo']['error'];
$tiposPermitidos = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png');
$tamanhoPermitido = 6024 * 3000;
if ($arqError == 0)
{
    if(array_search($arqType, $tiposPermitidos) === false)
    {
    $retorno = '<span class="no">O tipo de arquivo enviado é invalido!</span>' ;
    }
    elseif ($arqSize > $tamanhoPermitido)
    {
    $retorno = '<span class="no">O tamanho do arquivo enviado e maior que o limite!</span>';
    }
    else
    {
        $pasta = 'images_sitios/';
        $extensaoTemp = explode('.',$arqName);
        $extensao = strtolower(end($extensaoTemp));
        $nome = time(). '.' . $extensao;
        $upload = move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $nome);

        if ($upload === true)
        {
        $ficheiro = $pasta.$nome;                                                                    
        }

        else
        {
        $retorno = '<span class="no">Nao foi possivel fazer o upload da imagem!</span>';
        }
    }                         
}

if(empty($ficheiro))
{
$retorno = '<span class="quase">Insira a imagem!</span>';
}         

if(empty($retorno))
{
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sitio (nome_sitio, horario, contato, morada, imagem, id_tipo, id_freguesia) VALUES ('$nomesitio','$horario','$contato','$morada','$ficheiro','$tipo','$freguesias')") or die (mysql_error());

    if($query === true)
    {
    $sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Sitio inserido com sucesso!</span>';
    echo $sucesso;
    }
}
else
{
echo $retorno;
}

} //END IF
?>
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: general programming tip: Use blanks in favour of tabs. Then you won't have such formatting problems. Most text editors provide this option.

Comment: http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm (or any other image uplading class, there are many of them). About thumb path - i would rather create two folders - one for thumbs, one for big images - and save files under same name -> so you will need one field in db table for this.

Comment: So you are saying to after create thumb, move that file to like images_sitios/thumbs and use the same name? So i should use the $nome to put the name on the thumb, right? so they got the same name..

Comment: @PedroFidalgo - yes, i do it so, maybe somebody else have another idea, but this is easier to me. However, resizing of images/removing of main image is simple - but somehow... boring :). So, use one good class for it. :)

Comment: Ok so i got this working. WHen i insert a place, the image is resized to 800x600 to images_sitios/ and a thumb is generated to images_sitios/thumbnails. And the name is the same, so i think i got what i want :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [resize class](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/) to perform your image resizing.

```
// *** Include the class  
include("resize-class.php");  

$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
file_put_contents("sample.jpg", $data);

// *** 1) Initialize / load image  
$resizeObj = new resize('sample.jpg');  

// *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)  
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(800, 600, 'crop');
```